# Working back and forth with DataFrame and nparray in Pipeline transformers

Tags: scikit-learn, pandas, numpy

**Little backstory** : I've recently purchased the book Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and Tensorflow and I've started trying to apply what I've read so far in the book. Before this, I tested my knowledge on the [Kaggle Titanic](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic) "competition". I now want to refactor my code to use some good practices I learned while reading the book.

At some point, the author talks about `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline`. I started writing my own `Transformers` to populate my pipeline.

The problem I face is that, in some transformers, I'd use some `pandas` functions, in other `numpy` functions and I keep converting my dataset back and forth.

I did some research and din't find anything useful, it would be of great help if someone can answer the following questions:

1. Are there good practices concerning `Pipeline`?
2. Should I stick to `pandas`, `numpy`, is it a good practice to convert back and forth?